# Logbook for daily activity with automatic hour count

Tags: arrays, python

I am writing a logbook at work in which I note down when I started, left and how much of a break I took in between. I do this for every day, but I would like to use the result to display it in a table at the end of the file. So basically I would like to store the individual numbers in an array style as in matlab or python (I have tried the embedded python environment in LaTeX).
Then I want to display the hours over every day and then later on in a table at the end of the file. I furthermore want to summarize after each week and month what I have done in that interval without having to do it all by hand.

So far, I do something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newcommand{\week}{0}
\newcommand{\total}{0}

\section{September 2013}

\newcommand{\start}{9} \newcommand{\finish}{18.30} \newcommand{\brk}{1}     \FPeval{\day}clip(\finish - \start - \brk)}
\FPeval{\week}{clip(\week + \day)} \FPeval{\total}{clip(\total + \day)}
\paragraph{02. September 2013, Mon - \start /\finish (-\brk h) $\rightarrow$ \day h}
\begin{itemize}
\item did this
\item did that
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mention having tried the "embedded python environment", which is presumably the `python` package.  If you do want to do this with a Python-style approach, you might also take a look at the [`pythontex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) package.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your needs, but before reinvent the wheel, it is worth look at the `labbook` document class (in the package of the same name in both TeX Live and MiKTeX):

> This class is designed to typeset laboratory journals that contain
>   chronologically ordered records about experiments. From the
>   sectioning commands, an experiment index is generated. The class   is
>   based on the KOMA-Script class scrbook.cls. There can be sev­eral in­dex en­tries for one ex­per­i­ment.

Comment: Hey,thanks for the input. While this is a handy class, it doesnt quite do what I need. Anybody else have any input?